# Shift column values with condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table:

```
id | value
-----------
1  | 1
2  | 0
3  | 0
4  | 3
```

Assuming that we are at the first row. I want to look ahead until I meet a non-zero value and shift it back. If a value is zero, the next_value will be zero too.

```
id | value | next_value
-----------------------
1  | 1     | 3
2  | 0     | 0
3  | 0     | 0
4  | 3     | Nan
```

I try to use shift function in pandas but you can only predefine a shift length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index the dataframe where `value` is different than `0` and assign a shifted version of the column:

```
m = df.value.ne(0)
df.loc[m, 'value'] = df.loc[m, 'value'].shift(-1)

    id  value
0   1    3.0
1   2    0.0
2   3    0.0
3   4    NaN
```

Comment: Although I tested it, and it works! But to understand correctly, the index of the right term will overwrite the index in the left term? And where there is no value to replace, it will be NaN?

Comment: First you're performing boolean indexing on the dataframe. So you're left with a slice of the original dataframe where value is not 0. Then you're just assigning the shifted version @Thien So this just works with `df.loc[m, 'value']`, the rest remains unchanged